# C# Regular Expression to insert "_" after third, then seventh character with a new line after the eighth character

Tags: c#, regex, string

I was wondering if someone could help. I am trying to change a string in the below format:

goeirjew98rut34ktljre9t30t4j3der

to be outputted as below:

geo_irje_w

98r_ut34_k

tlj_re9t_3

0t4_j3de_r

So insert an underscore after the third and seventh characters and insert a new line after the eighth.

After doing some reading I thought the best way to do this might be via a regular expression such as the example at the below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

However I am not sure how to modify this for my needs. Any help what so ever would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure you need a regex to do that.

Comment: Regex is particularly useful to extract data, this is a little off. Why can't you just use a loop with a few `if`s?

Comment: You only need to use the String.Substring method, String.Insert method and a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily solved by a regular expression and a Replace, like this:

```
var s = "goeirjew98rut34ktljre9t30t4j3der";
Regex.Replace(s, @"(\w{3})(\w{4})(\w{1})", "$1_$2_$3\n").Dump();
```

Comment: I actually like this solution better than my own, provided that you're comfortable with reading RegExes.  OP if you use this, I'd leave a comment for yourself as to what it does, for maintainability and/or learning until you're more comfortable with them.  I do this with the more complicated ones I have.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely something that is best solved with a quick loop:

```
string s = "goeirjew98rut34ktljre9t30t4j3der";

var outputs = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 8)
{
    string sub = s.Substring(i, Math.Min(8, s.Length - i));
    if(sub.Length > 3)
        sub = sub.Insert(3, "_");

    if (sub.Length > 8)
        sub = sub.Insert(8, "_");

    outputs.Add(sub);
}
```

Comment: Cheers tencntraze that is brilliant thanks for your help. I am only just starting with programming and C# so not sure of the best way to do things yet but reading over this it seems perfect. Again thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not insert char in string by this rule, but I hope this code be useful for you.

```
public string Decode(string str)
{
    var state = 0;
    var c = 0;
    var newStr = string.Empty;
    foreach (var ch in str)
    {
        c++;
        newStr += ch;
        if (state == 0 && c == 3)
        {
            newStr += "_";
            state = 1;
            c = 0;
        }
        if (state == 1 && c == 4)
        {
            newStr += "_";
            state = 2;
            c = 0;
        }
        if (state == 2 && c == 1)
        {
            newStr += "\r\n";
            state = 0;
            c = 0;
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make it so u can change everything on the fly and use stringextentions

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "goeirjew98rut34ktljre9t30t4j3der";
        var parts = str.SplitInParts(8); //Split in different parts
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            string formattedString = part.MultiInsert("_", 2, 6); //Insert your char on all position u want
            Console.WriteLine(formattedString);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
        if (partLength <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

        for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
            yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
    }

    public static string MultiInsert(this string str, string insertChar, params int[] positions)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length + (positions.Length * insertChar.Length));
        var posLookup = new HashSet<int>(positions);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(str[i]);
            if (posLookup.Contains(i))
                sb.Append(insertChar);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```